Assigning window.open causes a DOMException
I have an iframe embedded in a different domain that opens up a popup window in a different domain. I am trying to establish cross window communication and running into a bunch of XSS security measures stopping this. One thing I am attempting to do is to assign the window I am opening to a variable.
    let openedWindows = [];
    window.__open = window.open;

    window.open = function(url, name, features) {
        openedWindows.push(window.__open(url, name, features));
        console.log(openedWindows);
    }


    <button onclick="window.open('{{url}}', 'name', 'popup=true,width=300,height=300')></button>

However, when I try this I see that I get a DOMException. Is there no secure workaround here? I control the web app in the iframe and the webapp in the popup but not the webapp that the iframe is embedded in.
My goal is to be able to use window.postMessage to get data from the child popup to the embedded iframe.

Testing opening a page from a different domain logged openedWindows as Array [ Restricted  ] . I suspect the Restricted value represents a trigger for the error message to be produced later, but the code posted is not producing it.What kind of domain was hosting both the iframe and popup's source code when tested (localhost, intranet, public)?

@traktor I realised

Have you tried with the iframe and child window being on the same domain? If that works then put an iframe in the window for the domain you want and relay your message via that.

The popup and the iframe are from the same origin so that would work but the issue may be posting a message back from the pop up window to the iframe because the domain hosting the iframe is different and I cannot control that. @DavidBradshaw

@traktor It is localhost hosting them

Avoid lovalhost, use the external ip address instead

If the popup and iframe are from the same domain then I would expect the popup's window.opener to be a non-null reference to the window.object in the iframe. What is the actual outcome of testing?

No need. window.open returns the reference
let openedWindows = [];
const myOpen = (url, name, features) => {
  openedWindows.push(window.open(url, name, features));
  console.log(openedWindows);
};

button.addEventListener('click', () => myOpen({{url}}', 'name', 'popup=true,width=300,height=300'))

However, you will likely have issues accessing said window, since the content is not from your origin

Hm so I guess the problem is the domain hosting the iframe isn't owned by me so I can't control it. Is this a security policy that I won't be able to circumvent?

Yes. You can write a proxy on the server and use curl or other ways to access the other server, but then you might run into things like javascript rendered content

So instead of postMessage to the other window, I would just save the data to a data layer somewhere and fetch it (maybe constantly poll the db) to get data from one window to the other?

Yes, if the target server will allow it. Perhaps they have an API, please use that instead of scraping
